# Framework to use to build a hybrid app using angular2

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

Iam new to angular 2 and would want to build a hybrid app using angular2. I see that ionic framework can be used or nativescript can also be used. I have used cordova with angular1 but do not know if it supports angular 2 also. Which is the best framework to build a hybrid app using angular2 and why?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of mobile frameworks support angular 2, even  React native you can use React native in Angular 2.

I have use many different hybrid mobile frameworks and at last I find nativescript is best. (For non hybrid frameworks ,Qt is very good.)

For Angular 2: After rc 5, It is very stable.

Comment: The questioner asked for hybrid framework not mobile framework. Can you now list 10 of  `lots of mobile frameworks` ?

Comment: Hello Mohsen, He is asking Mobile framework because he mentioned: ionic framework and nativescript ---which are Mobile framework.

Answer (score 0):

Both NativeScript and Ionic will enable you to build a mobile application using JavaScript (Angular 2).

With Ionic (version 2) you can use html and creating new elements is relatively easy, you just style the element with css. The application is hybrid as you mentioned - native app with webview, where your code is executed.

With NativeScript you use XML and the set of elements you can use is limited to components that are mapped to native components (ie. there is no html select box). The result is native application - no webview.

My opinion (I have used both technologies recently) - With Ionic you are faster in development and prototyping. With NativeScript you get better performance.

Both of these technologies are being developed and are not stable - because Angular2 is not stable as well.

Comment: Can just cordova be used instead of using these frameworks. Does it support angular 2?

Comment: Sure, but you need to set up your whole developemnt stack on your own - that includes setting up a module loader, typescript compilation etc. You can find some boilerplates on [github](https://github.com/Hantse/cordova-angular2/tree/master/CordovaAngular2Boilerplate) to get you started. But the reason behind frameworks like Ionic is to help you - they do the stuff behind the scenes so that you dont have to. My guess is you will spend more time on setup and maintenance than you would spend on learning Ionic / NativeScript.